# HSQLDB Load initial script on startup

Tags: hsqldb

I am starting an **HSQLDB** in memory, what is the way to tell HSQLDB that on startup I would like it to execute initial scripts for me to populate the database ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of db schema management tool. For example http://www.liquibase.org/ which allows to initiate ant populate db with a XML or SQL configuration file.

**Update**

You can combine call luquibase during your application initialization phase:

```
DataSource dataSource = ...;
try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
    conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);

    Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(conn));
    Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("/changelog-master.xml",
            new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);

    liquibase.update("");
}

// do other useful things here
```

Comment: I am not using any backend. I want to run the HSQLDB in a docker container but on startup I would like it to be self initialised. As docker allows only 1 main process to be running.

Comment: @axy3yz: you can still use Liquibase for that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you give an example ?